# How to extract the values of a cell in a raster (in this case landcover type) with data points (coordinates) in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, coordinates, extract, raster

I have a data frame (called "events") of camera trap data with coordinates and want to extract the habitat type using a raster file for each location and add the habitat type to my data frame. How do I extract this using the raster and the data frame coordinates? How do I add this to another main data frame afterwards?

```
## Creating the raster file from a shapefile

myfile <- shapefile("dpky.lc5.shp")

myfile@data$VALUE<-as.numeric(myfile@data$VALUE) # VALUE gives the numeric code for habitat type.

sr <- "+init=EPSG:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

r <- raster(myfile, res=100, crs=sr)

myraster<-rasterize(myfile,r,field="VALUE")

myras_spdf <- as(myraster, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")

myras_df <- as.data.frame(myras_spdf)

## Data frame with coordinates

events <- read.csv("DPKY.Clean.csv",h=T,sep=";")

events.sp<-SpatialPoints(events[,c("Longitude","Latitude")],proj4string = CRS("+init=EPSG:4326"))

events.sp
```

I have not been able to find any code for this problem yet specific to my problem. I did manage using another .gri file but that code doesn't work for this.

Comment: for me, this is impossible to say without some sample data..

Comment: How do I share the data with you?

Comment: You should not share your data. Instead you should create some example data like I do in my answer, and as you can see in numerous questions on this site.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have points and polygons, and what to query their values with points. In other words, extract the values for the points from the polygons. If that is the case, it makes no sense to create a RasterLayer (and/or a SpatialPixels) object.

Always provide some example data (`p` has the polygons, `d` is a data.frame with coordinates)

```
library(raster)
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
set.seed(10)
d <- coordinates(spsample(p, 4, "regular"))
colnames(d) <- c("lon", "lat")
d <- data.frame(id=1:nrow(d), d)
```

Solution

```
x <- extract(p, d[,c("lon", "lat")])
```

Now you can do

```
cbind(d, x[,c(4,6)])
#  id      lon      lat     NAME_1           NAME_2
#1  1 5.889636 49.53576 Luxembourg Esch-sur-Alzette
#2  2 6.176340 49.53576 Luxembourg       Luxembourg
#3  3 5.889636 49.82246   Diekirch          Redange
#4  4 6.176340 49.82246   Diekirch         Diekirch
```

Or something like this

```
d$NAME_2 <- x$NAME_2
d
#  id      lon      lat           NAME_2
#1  1 5.889636 49.53576 Esch-sur-Alzette
#2  2 6.176340 49.53576       Luxembourg
#3  3 5.889636 49.82246          Redange
#4  4 6.176340 49.82246         Diekirch
```